# How do I set the global PATH environment in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables, path

The group policy in our environment overwrites the PATH variable every time I log on and, as I run a 'non-standard' computer, it gets it completely wrong (C:\Windows vs C:\WINNT, missing directories etc). Currently, I manually change it every time I log on, but that is starting to get tiresome.

If I use the SET command to change the PATH variable in a batch file, it only has local scope so the change only applies to the commands in the batch file.

```
set PATH=C:\WINNT;C:\WINNT\System32
set PATH
```

This batch file will output the new path, but if I run `set PATH` on the command line afterwards, it will still be the original path.

How do I set the *global* PATH environment in a batch file? Or is there another technique I can use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [setx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104.aspx) command:

```
setx PATH C:\WINNT;C:\WINNT\System32 /m
```

Setx is available in Windows 2003 and later, but can be downloaded in the [Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=49ae8576-9bb9-4126-9761-ba8011fabf38) for Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

This is edited in system preferences -> [Environment variables]. There you add paths to $PATH

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment, every time I log on. I want to do it in a batch file so it can be done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To set your path in the registry so that it propagates to , you can create a PowerShell script that uses some variation of this:

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", $Env:Path + ";newpart", "user")
```

But when I tried it just now then looked at System Properties>Environment Variables it not only added my test path, but doubled the existing one. So that problem needs to be worked out.

Based on [this page](http://softwaresalariman.blogspot.com/2008/01/add-path-environment-variable-in.html).